# DOMDocument->save() fails after user_abort is handled

Tags: php, xml, libxml2, php-7

In `PHP`, its possible to [register shutdown functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), which (sometimes gets ignored, however) is definetely called in my scenario, see below.

PHP/libxml supported by the [DOMDocument class in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) does not play along well w/ my registered [shutdown functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), if I want to call `->save()` (`->saveXML()` works fine) after [user abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) (e.g. from registered `shutdown function` or a class instance `destructor`). Related is also the [PHP connection handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php).

Let the examples speak:

**PHP version:**

```
php --version
PHP 7.1.4 (cli) (built: Apr 25 2017 09:48:36) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

**To reproduce user_abort** I'm running the php through **python2.7** `run.py`:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["/usr/bin/php", "./user_aborted.php"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# As this process exists here and the user_aborted.php
# has sleeps/blocks in for-cycle thus simulating a user-abort
# for the php subprocess.
```

The **php** script `user_aborted.php` to **try saving XML in shutdown function** :

```
<?php

ignore_user_abort(false);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml_track = $xml->createElement( "Track", "Highway Blues" );
$xml->appendChild($xml_track);

function shutdown() {
    global $xml;

    $out_as_str = $xml->saveXML();

    fwrite(STDERR, "\nout_as_str: " . var_export($out_as_str, true) . "\n");

    $out_as_file = $xml->save('out.xml');

    fwrite(STDERR, "\nout_as_file: >" . var_export($out_as_file, true) . "<\n");
    fwrite(STDERR, "\nerrors: \n" . var_export(libxml_get_errors(), true) . "\n");
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

$i = 2;

while ($i > 0) {
    fwrite(STDERR, "\n PID: " . getmypid() . " aborted: " . connection_aborted());
    echo("\nmaking some output on stdout"); // so user_abort will be checked
    sleep(1);
    $i--;
}
```

Now, if I run this script w/o user abort (simply calling PHP) with:
`php user_aborted.php` the **XML gets saved properly**.

**However** when calling this through `python2.7` (which **simulates the user abort** by exiting the parent process), `python2.7 run.py` the weirdest things happen:

- the `out_as_str` **value is fine, looks the XML** I wanted
- **BUT** the file `out.xml` **is an empty file**
- **ALSO** the `libxml_get_errors` reports FLUSH problems

The output w/ python looks:
python2.7 run.py

```
PID: 16863 aborted: 0
out_as_str: '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Track>Highway Blues</Track>
'

out_as_file: >false<

errors:
array (
  0 =>
  LibXMLError::__set_state(array(
     'level' => 2,
     'code' => 1545,
     'column' => 0,
     'message' => 'flush error',
     'file' => '',
     'line' => 0,
  ))
)
```

*Sorry for the long post, but I was looking through PHP/libxml2 code the whole day w/o any success. :/*

Comment: This happens when the `$xml->save('out.xml');` called from a class destruct too.

Comment: @andras.tim right, i've updated the title / text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

It turns out this is due to a fix for a previous bug.

Links:

- [previous PHP bug ticket which fix introduced the deffect](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71536)
- [commit that introduces the deffect (GitHub)](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/93592a9c08c37184ebcb5c1274f240d257e3e3e1)

The linked `php_libxml_streams_IO_write` function is the `writecallback`  (set [in ext/libxml/libxml.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/libxml/libxml.c#L466)) for the buffer of the `docp` object, which is handed over for the `libxml` call on [ext/dom/document.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/dom/document.c#L1593). Ending up in [libxml xmlIO.c](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/229d1f93ceaa5e29a1e8455e73a7f346993d20b3/xmlIO.c#L1051) where the buffer is `NULL` hence the file given over for `->save(*)` does not get written.

**Workaround:**

Use the `->saveXML()` to get the XML representation in string and write it using `file_put_contents(*)` by "hand":

```
$xml_as_str = $xml->saveXML();
file_put_contents('/tmp/my.xml', $xml_as_str);
```